# Problema ao fazer login no backend do magento

Tags: mysql, magento

Fiz uma cópia espelho de um site em magento.
O Site roda bonitinho no *front-end*, carrega rápido e tudo mais, porem quando tento acessar o *admin*, alem de demorar pra caramba a página de *login* (prox a 2,3 minutos), quando faço o *login*, ele retorna esse erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Trace:
#0 /home/floraweb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/floraweb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/floraweb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `admin_u...', Array)
#3 /home/floraweb/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `admin_u...', Array)
#4 /home/floraweb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(725): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#5 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(352): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#6 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Mysql4/User.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_User), '1', NULL)
#7 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Admin_Model_Mysql4_User->load(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_User), '1', NULL)
#8 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php(281): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('1')
#9 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(48): Mage_Admin_Model_User->reload()
#10 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1228): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1209): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(497): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(152): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#17 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /home/floraweb/public_html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/floraweb/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

O DNS não esta configurado pois ainda estou desenvolvendo, estou acessando através do IP e já atualizei essa informação nos campos "web/unsecure/base_url" e "web/secure/base_url". O Site estava funcionando bonitinho, até o painel *admin* estava entrando. Este problema apareceu de um dia para o outro.

Comment: Você está enfrentando problemas com o seu banco de dados. Ou ele está instável ou a sua aplicação está consumindo mais recursos do que ele pode oferecer e seu provedor de hospedagem está provocando este erro pra chamar sua atenção. Confira também seus dados de conexão no app/etc/local.xml ...

Comment: Amigo, primeiramente, obrigado por responder.
Sim, é um erro de Mysql, mas não acredito que o problema seja com o Banco de dados, senão o front-end tbm estaria dando zica, o documento local.xml esta devidamente configurado...Acredito que o problema esteja nos recursos mesmo, algo esta fazendo com que a consulta dure mais do que o tempo permitido na hora de acessar o backend.

Answer (score 0):

"MySQL server has gone away" significa que o tempo de carregamento SQL demorou mais que o normal e foi encerrado, esse erro ocorre quando o PDO_MySQL ou mcrypt não foram instalados em seu servidor que estar a executar o magento.

Revise as configurações mínimas e extensões recomendadas para se utilizar o magento, certifique que tais extensões estão instaladas em seu servidor:

```
PDO_MySQL
simplexml
mcrypt
hash
GD
DOM
iconv
curl
SOAP (PARA Webservices API)
```

Após corrigir tais questões, remove a pasta localdeinstalacao/var/cache e localdeinstalacao/var/session do seu magento e atualize a página para tentar novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Já encontrei esse problemas em algumas lojas,
Você deverá verificar também a quantidade de conexões permitidas (aumentar) no banco juntamente com o timeout da conexão (aumentar o tempo de espera).